# convert UTF-8 to CP1252 in ubuntu with PHP or bash shell

Tags: windows, ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, cp1252

I have a question about converting UTF-8 to CP1252 in Ubuntu with PHP or SHELL.

Background : Converting a csv file from UTF-8 to CP1252 in Ubuntu with PHP or SHELL, copy file from Ubuntu to Windows, open file with nodepad++.

Environment :

- Ubuntu 10.04
- PHP 5.3
- a file csv with letters (œ, à, ç)

Methods used :

1. With PHP

   `iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", "content of file")`

   or

   `mb_convert_encoding("content of file", "UTF-8", "CP1252")`

   If I check the generated file with 

   `file -i name_of_the_file`

   It displayed :

   `name_of_the_file: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`

   I copy this converted file to windows and opened with notepad++, in the bottom of the right, we can see the encoding is ANSI

    And when I changed the encoding from ANSI to Windows-1252, the specials characters were well displayed.
2. With Shell 

    `iconv -f UTF-8 -t CP1252" "content of file"`

    The rest will be the same .

Question :
 1. Why the command file did not display directly CP1252 or ANSI but ISO-8895-1 ?
 2. Why the specials characters could be well displayed when I changed the encoding from ANSI to Windows-1252.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

CP1252 and ISO-8859-1 are very similar, quite often a file encoded in one of them would look identically as the file encoded in the second one. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) to see which characters are in Windows-1252 and not in ISO-8859-1.

Letters `à` and `ç` are encoded identically in both encodings. While ISO-8859-1 doesn't have an `œ` and CP1252 does, `file` might have missed that. AFAIK it doesn't analyse the entire file.

2.

"ANSI" is a misnomer used for the default non-Unicode encoding in Windows. In case of Western European languages, ANSI means Windows-1252. In case of Central European, it's Windows-1250, in case of Russian it's Windows-1251, and so on. Nothing apart from Windows uses the term "ANSI" to refer to an encoding.